# Ajax validation not working in jquery validation engine

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validation-engine

I am new to jquery validation engine and using it for validation of ItemNo in my asp.net mvc application. I am using following code in my view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ItemNo, new { @class="validate[required,ajax[ajaxCheckItemNo]]" })
```

following code in my jquery.validationEngine-en.js

```
"ajaxCheckItemNo": {
                // remote json service location
                "url": "/DrugManager/IsItemNoAlreadyExists",
                "extraDataDynamic": ['#ItemNo'],
                // error
                "alertText": "* This name is already taken",
                // if you provide an "alertTextOk", it will show as a green prompt when the field validates
                "alertTextOk": "* This name is available",
                // speaks by itself
                "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
            }
```

and following code in my controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult IsItemNoAlreadyExists(string ItemNo, int DrugID = 0, bool IsAddForm = true)
    {
        bool? ReturnValue = null;

        try
        {
            /* returns true/false */
            ReturnValue = ObjDrugManager.IsItemNoAlreadyExists(ItemNo, DrugID, IsAddForm);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            /* Catch Exception Here */                
        }

        return Json(new { ReturnValue });
```

when I run code my break comes to my server code also returns value but on my view only loading message is display like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        public JsonResult IsItemNoAlreadyExists(string ItemNo, int DrugID = 0, bool IsAddForm = true)
        {
            bool? ReturnValue = null;
     ArrayList validationResult = new ArrayList();
            validationResult.Add("ItemNo");
            try
            {
                /* returns true/false */
                ReturnValue = ObjDrugManager.IsItemNoAlreadyExists(ItemNo, DrugID, IsAddForm);

 if(ReturnValue ==false)
            {
                validationResult.Add(ReturnValue );
                validationResult.Add("Error message.");
            }
            else{
                validationResult.Add(ReturnValue);
                validationResult.Add("success message");
            }       
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                /* Catch Exception Here */                
            }

            return Json(validationResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i resolved it by returning json in this format in ajax response.

```
["field_id",true]
```